# Is it possible to make Facebook stories available for everyone after 24 hours just like in Instagram?

Tags: facebook

In Instagram you can feature a story and it will remain visible for anyone after 24 hours. In Facebook you can't do this, but you archive them, and they will remain visible, but only for you, apparently. The place where Facebook stories are archived has a caption which says "only you can see your stories archive" and it has a padlock icon along to that caption.

Is it possible to make Facebook stories available for everyone after 24 hours just like in Instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of now it's not possible as Facebook has made it for 24 hours only.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/126560554619115?helpref=faq_content):

> **How long are photos and videos in my story available?**
>
> Each photo or video in your story is available in the [stories section](https://www.facebook.com/help/1860890874146432?helpref=faq_content) in Facebook and the Messenger app for 24 hours.
>   When you go [Live](https://www.facebook.com/help/1636872026560015?helpref=faq_content), the video will be available in your story for as long as you're live.
>
> You can always [delete a photo or video from your story](https://www.facebook.com/help/1660071974290052?helpref=faq_content).